j2v8 makes my process crashed when execute js. final stack stop at void v8::internal::CalculateLineEndsImpl
I use j2v8 in my program to help paint image. One v8 instance would be used three times and then it would be destoryed. but i noticed, it would crashed when failed to js execution throws exception. As the jvm crash log indicated, every time, it crashed at the same location.
enter image description here
how can i fix it or is there any way to troubleshoot?
